# Unable to refresh View C# MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Edit**: I got how to refresh the page on success, but it just creates 2 calls to my controller method, which is unnecessary and the page doesn't update on 1st call. Can anyone help to update the page on first call?

Now I am new to Ajax calls so, I don't know how to refresh my view Or Webgrid after executing my controller method.
And I am also unable to find whether success method is called or not in Ajax.
And I am facing this in every Ajax call, why View isn't updated when returned by controller method.

What I have done is, there is a `DropDownlist`,and on selecting a value and submitting displays a `webgrid`.

`Webgrid` has checkboxes and on selecting checkboxes and clicking on submit passes some data through AJax to controller method. The Data gets updated in DataBase **but it is not reflected in view Until I refresh it**.
How to refresh View automatically?

Any help would be appreciated.

I have a `View`  as follows:

```
          $("#save_btn").on("click", function () {
                var ischecked = 0;`enter code here`
            $('#tblFormentry').find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                if (this.checked) {


                var chck = $(this).attr("value");
                var hidden = $(this).closest('td').find(':hidden');

                villcode = villcode + "," + hidden.val();
                singlestring = singlestring + "," + chck;


            }

        });

        if ((singlestring != null && singlestring != "") && (villcode != null && villcode != "")) {
            alert(singlestring);
            if (confirm("Are you sure?") == true) {
                $.ajax({

                    url: "@Url.Action("getmultipleids", "Admin")",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { 'ids': singlestring, 'villcode': villcode },
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("body").html(result);
                        singlestring = "";
                        villcode = "";                            
                    },
                    failure: function (errMsg) {
                        alert(errMsg);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                singlestring = "";
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Please select at least 1 Entry!");
        }

    });

<div class=" col-md-10">
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetGridData", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "verifyentry_form", role = "form" }))
{

    @*@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(TempData["ErrorMessage"])))
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <strong>Error! </strong>@TempData["ErrorMessage"].ToString()
            <div style="display:none">@TempData.Remove("ErrorMessage")</div>
        </div>
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(TempData["Message"])))
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <strong></strong>@TempData["Message"].ToString()
            <div style="display:none">
                @TempData.Remove("Message")
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div class="panel-default box box-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Verify Entry</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.agency_id, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    @*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DistID, (SelectList)TempData["Districts"], "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.agency_id, (SelectList)@ViewBag.Agencylist, "Select", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddID" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=" row ">
                <input type="button" name="submitbtn" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="databtn"  />

            </div>

        </div>



    </div>
}

<div class="box box-primary" id="ajaxdiv">
    @if (ViewBag.formentry != null)
    {
        int PageSizeValue = 1;
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["Tbl_TraMstPageSizeValue"])))
        //{
        //    PageSizeValue = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Tbl_TraMstPageSizeValue"]) > 0 ? Convert.ToInt32(Session["Tbl_TraMstPageSizeValue"]) : 1;
        //}
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.formentry, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "ajaxdiv", rowsPerPage: 10, ajaxUpdateCallback: "DetailsUpdate");

        @grid.GetHtml(
         htmlAttributes: new { id = "tblFormentry" },
              tableStyle: " table table-bordered table-hover dataTable", headerStyle: "",

     mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    firstText: "<<",
    lastText: ">>",
    nextText: ">",
    previousText: "<",
    columns: new[]{
        @*grid.Column(header:"{checkall}",format:@<text>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Tbl_TraMstId" value="@item.agency_id" onclick="CheckClick(this)" />
            </text>,style:"TableCheckBoxStyle",canSort:false),*@
    grid.Column("district_name","District Name",canSort:false),
     grid.Column("block_name","Block Name",canSort:false),
     grid.Column("village_name","Village Name", canSort:false),
     grid.Column("name","Name", canSort:false),
     grid.Column("formno","Form No", canSort:false),
     grid.Column("agency_name","Agency Name", canSort:false),
     //grid.Column("Verify", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.formno)),

     grid.Column("Verify",format:@<text>
        <form method="post" action="" id="chckboxform">

            <input type="hidden" name="village_code" value="@item.village_code" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="formno" value="@item.formno" id="chckbox1" />

        </form>
    </text>,style:"tablebutton",canSort:false)

    })


    }

</div>


<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="save_btn" class="btn btn-primary" />
<input type="button" name="reset" value="Reset" id="reset_btn" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

**Following is the controller method** that is being called with the help of jQuery AJax call.

```
public ActionResult getmultipleids(string ids, string villcode)
    {
        //need verificatN date, verified, verification user = admin, formno, villagecode
        int i;
        string[] formno = ids.Split(',');
        string[] village_code = villcode.Split(',');

        DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("Entries");
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

        DataRow dr;
        DataColumn dc;

        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[5] {
            new DataColumn("verification_date", typeof(DateTime)),
            new DataColumn("verified", typeof(Char)),
            new DataColumn("verification_user", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("formno", typeof(Int64)),
            new DataColumn("village_code", typeof(string))
        });

        for (i = 1; i < formno.Count(); i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["verification_date"] = today;
            dr["verified"] = 'Y';
            dr["verification_user"] = "admin";
            dr["formno"] = Int64.Parse(formno[i]);
            dr["village_code"] = village_code[i];
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        try
        {

            actionResult = objfamilyBAL.Update_Entry(dt);
            TempData["Message"] = actionResult.Message;
            ViewBag.Agencylist = (SelectList)Session["ddlist"];

            if (ShowResultMessage(actionResult, true, false))
            {

                int op = 1;
                int agncyid = (int)Session["agency_id"];
                String WorkArea = Session["wrkArea"].ToString();

                actionResult = objfamilyBAL.Fetch_verify_griddata(op, agncyid, WorkArea);

                if (actionResult.IsResult)
                {
                    List<CommonTableEntity> family_entitylist = (List<CommonTableEntity>)actionResult.ObjResult;

                    ViewBag.formentry = family_entitylist;

                }


            }
            if (actionResult.IsErrorMessage)
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = actionResult.ErrMessage;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex.Message);
        }

        return View("VerifyEntry");

    }
```

Sorry for long post.

Comment: Most people will use a javascript framework for binding, like Angular, Aurelia, etc. These things take care of updating the UI for you once it is all setup.

Comment: Can you verify that the result of your ajax call is returning the right html content or not? Open the network tab in your browser's "developer tools" interface and view the results of the ajax call. If the correct html is being returned, verify the http status code. Should be something like a 200 for success. This should also be visible from the network tab. You can also debug from here to step into your code to see if it's going into your success event handler or not. 

Best guess is that the html being returned from your action method is wrong. Pass the viewmodel to the view?

Comment: I am getting into the success method of Ajax call, but idk what to write so that View is refreshed

Comment: usually, once you want to use ajax with mvc, most of the times you should return `PartialView` and inside the `success` method in the `$.ajax` you replace the returned result with the existing data by selecting the existing data through `$('#YourDataRegion')`

Comment: You mean  in this case -`$(#ajaxdiv).html = result;` ?, 
Here ajaxdiv is id of `<div>` in which webgrid is displayed
@Monah